# How to simulate WriteTimeout in netty?

Tags: java, tcp, timeout, netty

I am writing a TCP protocol implementation in netty. I want to use a `WriteTimeoutHandler` to detect slow consumers of server messages. However `Thread.sleep()`-ing in consumer's `channelRead()` method does not trigger any exceptions. Presumably because the timeout applies only to socket-to-socket communication, not the actual consumer message handling.

How can I simulate a write timeout in netty to test my implementation?

**EDIT: Other things I've tried:**

1. I tried to set "SO_SNDBUF" to a small value on a server side and
   send a big chunk of data (1GB) at once.
2. Additionally, I tried to use Wondershaper (a wrapper of linux's tc) to constraint bandwidth on the interfaces to 1kb/s.
3. Dropping the TCP packets on the INBOUND chain via iptables.

None of them helped.